# Haproxy path manipulation

Tags: url, proxy, haproxy, forward

In Google Cloud Platform we do have a haproxy which serves as proxy for our internal VPN and do   URL redirects from GCP DNS to proxy.mycompany.com (our haproxy) where we do further manipulation.

`Haproxy` is from image `2.0.8-alpine`

`Nginx` is based on image `1-alpine`

Lately I have installed nginx which serves static files.

Nginx is setup for `autoindex on`, accesible on url `static-files.mycompany.com`,  and configured to show root of a gcs-bucket. Therefore if you visit `static-files.mycompany.com` you will see content of gcs-bucket:

- directory `static-files`
- any file in a bucket.

`static-files` directory contains static website files which were generated by [hugo](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo).
Those files contain paths like `/docu/file.md`

I've managed to configure haproxy that it will forward any requests for url `website.mycompany.com` to `static-files.mycompany.com/static-files` and show the generated static website by configuring this in `backend section` of haproxy config:

```
acl p_root path -i /
http-request set-path /static-files/\1 if p_root
```

Every time I visit `website.mycompany.com` the path is redirected to `website.mycompany.com/static-files` (which is actually `static-files.mycompany.com/static-files` )

However, the site is broken:

- css is not loading, file is located in / and the requests aims for  `website.mycompany.com/mycss.file`, but the file can be found under `website.mycompany.com/static-files/mycss.file` due to path manipulation above
- Every link on site dead,  requests `website.mycompany.com/my-link-to-file` but file is under 
  `website.mycompany.com/static-files/my-link-to-file`

I have a limited possibility to configure haproxy, most probably I can add parameters to existing backend and frontend section, here I am providing ***parameters I cannot change***:

```
    global
    log stdout format raw local0 info
    maxconn  30000
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
resolvers vpc
    parse-resolv-conf
    hold valid 120s
defaults
    mode    http
    log     global
    option  dontlognull
    #option  tcplog
    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor
    option  redispatch
    maxconn 3000
    retries 3
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout client  50s
    timeout server  50s
    timeout tunnel  1h
    timeout client-fin 30s
    timeout http-keep-alive 4s
    balance roundrobin
    default-server check resolvers vpc
    default-server on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
    default-server max-reuse 100

frontend http
    bind *:80
    redirect scheme https code 302 if !{ ssl_fc }
    monitor-uri /_healtz
    use_backend %[hdr(host),lower]

frontend https
    bind *:443 ssl no-sslv3 crt /config/haproxy_certificate.pem alpn http/1.1,h2
    http-response add-header Via 1.1\ %[env(HOSTNAME)]
    http-request add-header Via 1.1\ %[env(HOSTNAME)]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    http-request capture req.hdr(Host) len 40
    http-request capture req.hdr(User-Agent) len 120
    use_backend %[hdr(host),lower]

backend proxy.mycompany.com
    stats enable
    stats uri /
```

I would like to achieve the following:

By visiting `website.mycompany.com` I will be forwarded to `static-files.mycompany.com/static-files` in the background, however the URL will remain as `website.mycompany.com` and therefore the generated static website paths remain working and so the static site. Or Am I mistaken ?

I am open to any reasonable suggestion.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was quite simple in the end

```
http-request replace-uri ([^/:]*://[^/]*)?(.*) \1/static-files\2
```

Did the trick.

edit:

to avoid and infinite loop of /static-files/static-files/

```
    acl remove_static-files path_beg -i /architecture-diagrams
    http-request replace-uri ([^/:]*://[^/]*)?(.*) \1/static-files\2 if !remove_static-files
```